# How to click on pseudo element in protractor

Tags: protractor, pseudo-element

I am new to protractor.
I need to click on pseudo element:
label svg="switch"
before
after
/label

I need to click on before or after, because clicking on html tag label which is parent for pseudo elements isn't working, it's not changing switcher position

Comment: I have such a code:                                                                                        <label for="activity-override">                                                                               ::before                                                                                                              ::after                                                                                                         </label>

Answer (score 0):

@Ihor Khvalbota

You try clicking the element based on the x and y offset values. Capture the position of the element using getLocation() and use relative position from it.

Comment: Thanks krishnarajanr! I'm glad to get help from you, but I'm not a developher. I have only this code: <label for="con-term-override">::before ::after</label>. And I need to click on before or after, if I click on label, it doen't give me exoected result. Thanks.